How to proxy SignalR negotiate request from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core server?
I'm currently working on a big ASP.NET -> ASP.NET Core migration.
The goal is to proxy requests to ASP.NET Core server via the old server.
I created a proxy controller in ASP.NET that passes through all of the requests.
The problem is SignalR. Although I know that JS client needs to know which type of server (JQuery vs MS SignalR client) it connects to, I don't want to put ASP.NET Core URL server into the frontend code.
Is there a way to proxy SignalR negotiation requests via ASP.NET, so even though the initial request is to the old server, the connection will be established with the new one?
I tried a few different approaches with request forwarding or OWIN middleware, but I can't get it to work. I'm using the MS SignalR library in the frontend when using the new server.

Hi @Mr Patience, it seems to use OWIN middleware is a good way. Pls check your design and ensure your client-side SignalR code points to the proxy endpoint.
